# Passing object method as the object argument value

Tags: python, inheritance, methods, folium

I made a `BetterMarker` class that inherits from `folium.Marker` which is a geographic point object that can be added to a `folium.Map` object which produces a Leaflet HTML map.

```
import folium, datetime

class BetterMarker(folium.Marker):

    def __init__(self, latitude, longitude, **kwargs): 
        super().__init__([latitude, longitude], **kwargs)
        self.latitude = latitude

    def north_or_south(self):
        if self.latitude > 0:
            return "North"
        else:
            return "South"
```

I can now initialize`BetterMarker` and add its instance to a `folium.Map` object:

```
mymap = folium.Map() # Create Map object
bm = BetterMarker(30, 40, popup = "Hi there")
bm.add_to(mymap) # Add BetterMarker object to Map
mymap.save("mymap.html") # Save the map with the marker into HTML
```

The code above works just fine producing the following map:

[image]

However, instead of using the string `Hi there` in `bm = BetterMarker(30, 40, popup = "Hi there")` I want to use `bm.north_or_south()`:

```
bm = BetterMarker(30, 40, popup = bm.north_or_south())
```

Of course, the above wouldn't work. The code below would work, but it means initializing the class two times:

```
bm = BetterMarker(30, 40)
bm = BetterMarker(30, 40, popup = bm.north_or_south())
```

What's a sane way to do this?  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Best would be to do these changes inside your `__init__()` function, not during object initialization. `if not popup: self.popup = ...`

Comment: @Felipe not sure what you're trying to do with `if not popup`. Why do I need to check if popup is None?

Comment: Because you didn't pass it here `bm = BetterMarker(30, 40)`, but then attempted to re-initialize the object by passing it here `bm = BetterMarker(30, 40, popup = bm.north_or_south())`. So instead, if inside `BetterMaker` you have `if not popup:`, then you can skip the process of initializing the class twice, and always setting `popup` to the function call `north_or_south` if it is not passed to the constructor.

Comment: @Felipe even if I put an `if not popup` in `__init__`, again `bm = BetterMarker(30, 40, popup = bm.north_or_south())` will return `NameError: name 'bm' is not defined`

Comment: Of course it will give you that error -- the idea is to get rid of the double object initialization. I added an example for you below.

Answer (score 3):

**updated according to comment**

My first attempt didn't fully understand the requirements.  I think some of the other answers are on the right track.  Here's a way that works:

```
class BetterMarker(folium.Marker):

    def __init__(self, latitude, longitude, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['popup_method']:
            kwargs['popup'] = kwargs['popup_method'](latitude, longitude, **kwargs)
            del kwargs['popup_method']
        super().__init__([latitude, longitude], **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def quadrant(latitude, longitude, **kwargs):
        if latitude > 0 and longitude > 0:
            return "North East"
        elif latitude > 0 and longitude <= 0:
            return "North West"
        elif latitude <= 0 and longitude > 0:
            return "South East"
        else:
            return "South West"
```

As for calling, it's important to pass only the method and not to call it by including parentheses:

```
bm = BetterMarker(-30, 40, popup_method=BetterMarker.quadrant)
```

Notice I made a new keyword parameter called popup_method since popup meant the text.  Also, I added longitude and kwargs to the popup method's signature so those methods have access to everything the caller passed.

Comment: The BetterMarker class will have other methods  besides north_or_south and the user may want to assign these method calls to popup sometimes:
`bm = BetterMarker(30, 40, popup = bm.north_or_south())
bm = BetterMarker(30, 40, popup = bm.cold_or_hot())`
etc.

Therefore, hardcoding `north_or_south` in `__init__` wouldn't work.

Comment: ok, updated with better understanding of what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Relating to comments in question. Something like so:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.alert = kwargs['alert']

    def print_alert(self):
        print(self.alert())

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "alert" not in kwargs:
            kwargs['alert'] = self.custom_alert() # Notice here.

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def custom_alert(self):
        return "Custom Alert"

Bar().print_alert() # >>> Custom Alert
```

---

#### Edit

As per the comment below, you could simply define the method(s) as [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.alert = kwargs["alert"]

    def print_alert(self):
        print(self.alert()) # Notice we DO call the variable.


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "alert" not in kwargs:
            kwargs["alert"] = self.default_alert

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def default_alert():
        return "Custom Alert!"

    @staticmethod
    def random_alert():
        return "Random Alert!"


a = Bar()
a.print_alert()

b = Bar(alert=Bar.random_alert)  # Notice we do not CALL the method.
b.print_alert()
```

outputs:

```
default
rand
```

Comment: I cannot hardcode popup/alert by assigning the north_or_south/custom_alert method call to it. There might be more than just one method that the user may assign to popup/alert after they instantiate the subclass.

Comment: Gotcha. The original question wasn't fully defined so I made some assumptions. Check out the edit above -- you could use `@staticmethods` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[edit] Maybe just pass popup generating function as a keyword parameter?

```py
import folium, datetime

class CustomPopup:
       @staticmethod
       def north_or_south(latitude, longtitude, **kwargs):
        if latitude > 0:
            return "North"
        else:
            return "South" 

        ...other methods

class BetterMarker(folium.Marker):

    def __init__(self, latitude, longitude, **kwargs): 
        self.latitude = latitude
        if 'msg' in kwargs:
             kwargs['popup'] = kwargs['msg'](latitude, longtitude, **kwargs)
        super().__init__([latitude, longitude], **kwargs)


mymap = folium.Map() # Create Map object
bm = BetterMarker(30, 40, msg=CustomPopup.north_or_south)
bm.add_to(mymap) # Add BetterMarker object to Map
mymap.save("mymap.html")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not a solution because of the reason I explain in the comment I added to Felipe's answer above.

Comment: What about move popup method to other class and passing it as argument to marker class?

Answer (score 0):

you could try making north_or_south a static method

```
@staticmethod
def north_or_south(latitude):
    if latitude > 0:
        return "North"
    else:
        return "South"
```

This makes it runnable from either an object or an object class, but the function itself doesn't know anything about the object it is being run from nor the class, so you can no longer have

```
self.north_or_south()
```

as the function doesn't know anything about the object. Instead we pass the latitude as an argument

```
self.north_or_south(self.latitude)
```

and voila, it works. The code gets a little longer but the function no longer needs an object from where to be run. So in your problem you would simply have

```
bm = BetterMarker(30, 40, popup = BetterMarker.north_or_south(40))
```